# Use Webhook Response As Part of Assistant Response

Tags: azure-functions, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

Trying to get Dialogflow to respond with webhook response.

I've got Dialogflow receiving the payload without issue, however I cannot get Google to tell me what that data is.

JSON payload below.

```
{
    "payload": {
      "google": {
        "expectUserResponse": false,
        "richResponse": {
          "items": [
            {
              "simpleResponse": {
                "textToSpeech": "this is a simple response"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

At this point, I feel like I'm missing a setup option somewhere.

Dialogflow bot also shows an empty response.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not following the crux of the story.  Are you saying you have a dialog flow which has an intent.  The intent has an associated fulfillment and a webhook is called.  The webhook is then responding with shown JSON.   What do you mean when you then say "I cannot get Google to tell me what that data is"?

Comment: It seems that Dialogflow is not compatible with Azure functions, refer to https://medium.com/@yoichiro/how-to-use-actions-on-google-client-library-on-azure-functions-node-js-178d5ecd04e3 for the workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Dialogflow is not compatible with Azure Function you can track the open issue for the same in [github repo](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/issues/197).

To workaround this you can build your actions for Google Assistant with Azure Function using Google Client Library.

[Here](https://medium.com/@yoichiro/how-to-use-actions-on-google-client-library-on-azure-functions-node-js-178d5ecd04e3) is the very nice article that you can refer.

Comment: Wow, absolutely infuriating! Thank you.

Although I'm not using nodejs for this, I'm using C#, is this across all languages?

Comment: I haven't tried with C# but here is some thing that I found which can help you. https://github.com/LindaLawton/actions-on-google-dotnet